# how to obtain the strong convexity inequality

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

I was playing around with the [strong convexity](https://xingyuzhou.org/blog/notes/strong-convexity) definition and got stuck at some point. I was wondering if someone could kindly help me out.

We say that function $f$ is strongly convex if

$1) f(x) \geq f(y) + \xi^T(x- y) + \frac{\mu}{2}||x-y||^2$ for $\mu >0$ and $\forall x, y \in dom f$

Now, suppose $f$ is convex and let

$h(x) = f(x) -\frac{\mu}{2}||x||^2$

which is also convex. If $\xi \in \partial f(y)$, then $\xi - \mu y \in \partial h(y)$.

Then, I can use the definition of convexity for function $h$.

$h(x) \geq h(y) + (\xi - \mu y)^T (x-y)$. Now, let us replace $h$ by $ f -\frac{\mu}{2}||x||^2$.

$f(x) -\frac{\mu}{2}||x||^2 \geq f(y)  -\frac{\mu}{2}||y||^2 + (\xi - \mu y)^T (x-y)$

$f(x) \geq f(y)  + \frac{\mu}{2}||x||^2 -\frac{\mu}{2}||y||^2 + \xi^T(x-y) -  \mu y^Tx + \mu ||y||^2$

This is where I got stuck. I was expecting to obtain the inequality (1), however, I am making a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just observe that
$$
\frac{\mu}{2}\|x\|^2-\frac{\mu}{2}\|y\|^2+{\mu}\|y\|^2=\frac{\mu}{2}\|x\|^2+\frac{\mu}{2}\|y\|^2
$$
and
$$
\frac{\mu}{2}\|x\|^2+\frac{\mu}{2}\|y\|^2-\mu y^Tx=\frac{\mu}{2}\|x-y\|^2.
$$